# Optimizing huge graph traversal with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to optimize this function which according to the *perf tool* is the bottleneck of archiving close to linear scaling. The performance gets worse when the number of threads go up, when I drill down the assembly code generated by *perf* it shows most of the time is spent checking for visited and not visited vertices. I've done a ton of google searches to improve the performance to no avail. Is there a way to improve the performance of this function? Or is there a thread safe way of implementing this function? Thanks for your help in advance!

```
typedef uint32_t vidType;
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
bool compare_and_swap(T &x, U old_val, V new_val) {
     return __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&x, old_val, new_val);
 }

template<bool map_vertices, bool map_edges>
VertexSet GraphT<map_vertices, map_edges>::N(vidType vid) const {
  assert(vid >= 0);
  assert(vid < n_vertices);
  eidType begin = vertices[vid], end = vertices[vid+1];
  if (begin > end || end > n_edges) {
    fprintf(stderr, "vertex %u bounds error: [%lu, %lu)\n", vid, begin, end);
    exit(1);
  }
  assert(end <= n_edges);
  return VertexSet(edges + begin, end - begin, vid);
}

void bfs_step(Graph &g, vidType *depth, SlidingQueue<vidType> &queue) {
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    QueueBuffer<vidType> lqueue(queue);

    #pragma omp for
    
    for (auto q_iter = queue.begin(); q_iter < queue.end(); q_iter++) {
      auto src = *q_iter;
      for (auto dst : g.N(src)) {
        //int curr_val = parent[dst];
        auto curr_val = depth[dst];
        if (curr_val == MYINFINITY) { // not visited
          //if (compare_and_swap(parent[dst], curr_val, src)) { 
          if (compare_and_swap(depth[dst], curr_val, depth[src] + 1)) {
            lqueue.push_back(dst);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    lqueue.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple threads accessing `lqueue` ... that's either a race, or if it's thread safe, going to cause a bottleneck itself. What does `compare_and_swap` do? What's `g.N` do? What's `vidType`? `curr_val = depth[dst]` is a copy, what's the cost of copying?

Comment: @ChrisMM, thanks for the quick response and pardon me I'm new to stackoverflow and still learning my way around. I edited the original question to include the things  you asked about. Actually from _perf_, copy took only 0.00 secs. thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're using a very traditional formulation of graph algorithms. Good for textbooks, not for computation. If you write this as a generalized matrix-vector product with the adjacency matrix you lose all those fiddly queues and the parallelism becomes quite obvious.

In your formulation, the problem is with the `push_back` function on the queue. That is hard to parallelize. The solution is to let each thread have its own queue, and then using a reduction. This works if you define the plus operator on your queue object to effect a merge of the local queues.

Comment: I'll investigate your solution and see how the performance turn out... thank you